# Which subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ can be the sizes of finite models?

Tags: logic, model-theory, computability

Let $T$ be a *finite* first order theory (equivalently a single sentence) in a *finite* language. It is clear that $\{n\in\mathbb{N}:\exists M, M\models T\land |M|=n\}$ is computable: to see if there is a model of size $n$ just enumerate all structures of size $n$ and check one by one if any of them satisfies $T$. I guess this argument actually gives an upper bound on the time complexity of that set.

Conversely which computable sets can arise in this way? I wonder if given a Turing machine we can find a theory whose (finite) models are exactly "truncations" of the running process of that Turing machine. Maybe this is also related to descriptive finite model theory?

Comment: We know that not only are these sets recursive, they are actually primitive recursive.

Comment: @MarkSaving They're a lot better than that, even - see either of the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, we can restrict attention to a single sentence $\varphi$. Your set of interest is called the [*spectrum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_sentence) of $\varphi$, and it is very well studied.

As one answer to your question (available in the linked wikipedia article), a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is the spectrum of some formula $\varphi$ if and only if it's [$\mathsf{NEXP}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEXPTIME)-time decidable.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Dangit, beat me by 20 seconds!

Answer (score 3):

This is the **finite spectrum problem**. It is know that $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is a finite spectrum (= a set of the type you describe) if and only if $X$ is decidable by a nondeterminstic Turing machine in exponential time; snappily "spectrums = $\mathsf{NEXPTIME}$." It is wildly open whether the complement of a spectrum is again a spectrum!

See the paper [Durand/Jones/Makowsky/More, *50 years of the finite spectrum problem*](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5495) for more background on this.

Comment: lol, fancy seeing you here :P